# Git problems, 'git not installed'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, bundle, gitlab

I have set up my github account, configured it with SSH and now I am trying to retrieve group work from gitlab. I have managed to pull the work so that it is on my machine but when I go to bundle install I encounter an error.

It says that I need to install git in order to gems from git repository.
I've added an image which might help.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if Git is installed in a folder with spaces or special character.

Try and unzip a [recent Git](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) (like [`PortableGit-2.3.7.1-dev-preview-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.3.7.windows.1/PortableGit-2.3.7.1-dev-preview-64-bit.7z.exe)) under `C:\Git`, and add that to your `PATH`:

```
set PATH=C:\Git\cmd;%PATH%
bundle install
```

The PATH issue was mentioned before in [issue 5027](https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/5027#issuecomment-49733947) and in "[Can't run `bundle update` on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19746748/6309)".

Comment: @Sprout does `git --version` return 2.3.7 (meaning, does your PATH detects the C:\GIt first)?

Comment: It returns: git is not an internal or external recognised command

Comment: @Sprout So start solving that: unzip Git in `C:\Git`, and type `set PATH=C:\Git\bin;%PATH`, as I mentioned. A `git --version` should then work. And then you can try again the `bundle install`.

Comment: Hi VonC, I have already unzipped and installed the PortableGit link you provided and typed the set Path (in my ruby on rails command window, is this correct?) and when I type git --version It is still not recognising the command

Comment: @Sprout that is because `C:\Git\bin` does not contain `git.exe`. Check how the `PortableGit-2.3.7.1-dev-preview-64-bit.7z.exe` has actually been uncompressed under `C:\Git`.

Comment: I can't see a git bin folder, here is my explorer window for C:\git http://imgur.com/FajGKqI

Comment: @Sprout Right, I forgot: `C:\Git\cmd`. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Okay, git is now recognised 2.3.7.windows.1 but now the bundle command is no longer recognised as a command

Comment: @Sprout I forgot a '`%`' in the answer. Open another `cmd` session to see if `bundle install` is recognized there, set your `PATH` in that new session: `set PATH=C:\Git\cmd;%PATH%`, and try again.

Comment: Yes, this looks to be working now! I thought it was odd that when I ran the path command I could no longer bundle.

Comment: @Sprout it was because `%PATH` is empty (as opposed to `%PATH%`), so the `PATH` was overridden with just `C:\Git\bin`.