# Install gem from github using Rail 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, wicked-pdf

I need to install `wicked_pdf gem` from github. I also updated `Gemfile` but when I run `bundle install` it gave me the following message.

```
You need to install git to be able to use gems from git repositories. For help
installing git, please refer to GitHub's tutorial at
https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git
```

I have the Gemfile which is given below.

> Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.19'
gem 'mysql'
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem "bcrypt-ruby", :require => "bcrypt"
gem 'momentjs-rails', '>= 2.8.1'
gem 'bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails', '>= 0.6.21'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0'
gem 'wicked_pdf', :github => 'mileszs/wicked_pdf', :branch => 'master'
```

I have already installed `git-cell` on my system and i am using win-7 64 bit. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: I am not sure bundler does this automatically, but to be able to pull from github, you need to `git init` first in your working directory.

Comment: Possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19746748/cant-run-bundle-update-on-windows

Comment: @think : Where I have to add git init.

Comment: just use it as a command before you `bundle install`. maybe your shell does not recognize git at all, so you will have to repeat those steps in the git shell or add git to your %PATH%.

Comment: @ think : I run like this git  init bundle install but it is throwing message git is not recognize as an internal or external command.Can you please provide the proper steps.But its working in win-xp.

Comment: try gem 'wicked_pdf' instead of gem 'wicked_pdf', :github => 'mileszs/wicked_pdf', :branch => 'master' then bundle install

Comment: @ jean : but by doing gem 'wicked_pdf' i can not generate pdf file.In my xp system i am able to generate by doing gem 'wicked_pdf', :github => 'mileszs/wicked_pdf', :branch => 'master' and bundle install but in my win-7 system i am getting this type of issue.